# Aplying 'K method' to make a custom scroll bar in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I am trying to make a custom scrollbar using the following method:

Scrollbar height is inversely proportional to content height.

```
scrollHeight ∝ 1 / contentHeight.

scrollHeight = k / contentHeight
```

So if we take constant of `k` 's value as 10000. (As the height of container of content is 100px and 100 times 100 is 10000). It's still not doing the job.

Can't figure out the problem. If words are confusing check out this [JS Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/2Cg7C/). I know the concept just can't figure out how to set the height of the scroller for dynamic content.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for supplying a Fiddle for this question, but we would rather the code was _in_ the question (Fiddles are fine I think as a supplementary). This ensures the question remains useful even if the external link breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#scroll').draggable({
        axis: 'y',
       containment: 'parent'
    });


    var contentHeight = $('p').height();
    $('.hey').html(contentHeight);

    var containerHeight = $('#scroll-cont').height();

    var k = 10000;

    var scrollerHeight = $('#scroll').height((k / contentHeight) / 2);
    $('.hey').append('<br>' + $('#scroll').height());




    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var offsetS = $('#scroll').offset().top * 2;
        $('#scroll-cont').scrollTop(offsetS);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrollbarHeight / scrolltrackHeight = visibleHeight / contentHeight`

`scrollbarHeight = scrolltrackHeight * visibleHeight / contentHeight`

For example, you content's height 1000px, and visible height is 250px. If your scrolltrack height is 240px (all visible space - 5px padding from top/bottom), then your scrollbar should be `240 * 250 / 1000 = 60`